# using objective-c with swift : cannot invoke 'function' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

let's say I have in my objective-c this:

```
typedef void (^DirectionBlock)(NSArray *steps, NSError *error);

-(void)requestWithStartPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)start endPoint:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)end travelMode:(NSString*)travel language:(NSString*)lng result:(DirectionBlock)resultBlock;
```

to call `requestWithStartPoint` in objective-c it will look like this:

```
Direction *direction = [[Direction alloc] init];
[direction requestWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint travelMode:@"driving" language:@"en" result:^(NSArray *steps, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", [steps[0] description]);
    }
}];
```

I used this [converter](https://objectivec2swift.com/) here t get the swift equivalent and I got this:

```
var direction: Direction = Direction()
direction.requestWithStartPoint(startPoint, endPoint: endPoint, travelMode: "driving", language: "en", result: {(steps: [AnyObject], error: NSErrorPointer) in    if !error {
        NSLog("RESULT: %@", steps[0].description())
    }

})
```

But I got this error:

```
Cannot invoke 'requestWithStartPoint' with an argument list of type '(CLLocationCoordinate2D, endPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D, travelMode: String, language: String, result: ([AnyObject], NSErrorPointer) -> _)'
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with `NSArray` pointer being converted to `[AnyObject]`. Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: Option-click `requestWithStartPoint` in your Swift file to verify the method signature.

Comment: thx mate, by doing so I found its signature used [AnyObject]! and NSError! and not [AnyObject] and NSErrorPointer.
problem fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Aderstedt comment, by verifying method signature I found it used `[AnyObject]!` and `NSError!` and not `[AnyObject]` and `NSErrorPointer`.